# Rails link_to with acts_as_taggable_on_steroids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-taggable-on, clean-urls

I am using acts_as_taggable_on steroids and I am having problem with this piece of code that generates a link to a tag:

```
<%= link_to tag, tag_path(:id => tag.name) %>
```

when I access the URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/tags/rails
```

I get the error:

```
No action responded to rails. Actions: show
```

However, this URL works:

```
http://localhost:3000/tags/show/rails
```

I have defined the show action in my tags_controller.rb

```
class TagsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @stories = Story.find_tagged_with(params[:id])
  end
end
```

I have the following routes generated by rake:routes :

```
           tags GET    /tags(.:format)                             {:controller=>"tags", :action=>"index"}
                POST   /tags(.:format)                             {:controller=>"tags", :action=>"create"}
        new_tag GET    /tags/new(.:format)                         {:controller=>"tags", :action=>"new"}
       edit_tag GET    /tags/:id/edit(.:format)                    {:controller=>"tags", :action=>"edit"}
            tag GET    /tags/:id(.:format)                         {:controller=>"tags", :action=>"show"}
                PUT    /tags/:id(.:format)                         {:controller=>"tags", :action=>"update"}
                DELETE /tags/:id(.:format)                         {:controller=>"tags", :action=>"destroy"}
```

so I know that URL tags/rails points to the route tags/:id, and I've provided an additional param to link_to to assign the tag name as the :id param, but as you can see, it's not working. A forum suggested I use the to_param but I have not Tag model and the book suggested against it. Am I missing anything?

I am following the Sitepoint book Simply Rails 2

**EDIT:** added working URL, see top

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your route resource:

```
:requirements => { :id => /.*/ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Shooting in the dark here but should

`<%= link_to tag, tag_path(:id => tag.name) %>`

be

`<%= link_to tag, tag_path(:id => tag.id) %>`

or

`<%= link_to tag, tag_path(tag) %>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your link:

```
link_to tag.name, { :action => :tag, :id => tag.name }
```

---

I don't know what version of rails you're using, I'm assuming 3.

Basically, you're using the tag_path which goes off of the id. If you haven't changed anything, that means something like `tag/43`, tag with id 43. The reason you were suggested to override `to_param` is in case you want it to go off the name of the tag instead, so something like `tag/rails`. For that, you do something like this:

```
class Tag
  def to_param
    name
  end
end
```

Finally, you will have to change the show action to use the name, not the id. So `@stories = Story.find_tagged_with(params[:name])`. Then I believe that you will want to create a route to compensate for this, so above your `resources :tags`, add `match "/tags/:name" => "tags#show"`.

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like the difference in routes.rb between

```
resources :tags
```

and

```
resource :tags
```

The first will have as its default index action, the second will not have :index, but it will respond with show on default route.